# How do I debug inside the System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager

Tags: asp.net, debugging, iis, compilation

How do you debug events inside [System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.buildmanager.aspx)? And in what stage of the IIS/ASP.net lifecycle is it called?

The problem is I have some code that uses the [PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee818829.aspx) but does not seem to fire. So I am trying to figure out the best way to attach a debugger to it.

> There is some more details about the larger problem here
>   [Why does PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute() not work in SharePoint 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14374750/1399964) but I have broken it into
>   a smaller problem to try and make some progress.

I've only been able to identify the following call stack so far...

> BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods -> 
>   BuildManager.​GetPreStartInitMethodsFromAssemblyCollection()

Comment: Check the 'larger problem' question, I posted an answer that may clear this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working on a similar (or perhaps the same issue) and can give you the full stack trace. You can generate it yourself btw, just create a simple small MVC app and throw an exception in the method that you call using the PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute. You will get:

```
[ApplicationException: joe was here]
   MvcApplication2.JoeStart.Start() in c:\Users\Joe\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MvcApplication2\MvcApplication2\JoeStart.cs:18

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Start on type MvcApplication2.JoeStart threw an exception with the following error message: joe was here.]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +550
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +132
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath) +90
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +135
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +516

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Start on type MvcApplication2.JoeStart threw an exception with the following error message: joe was here.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9873784
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```